# Handle Errors on Android

Tags: android, error-handling

When I run an application that contain some kind of error, the emulator tells me that the application has stopped unexpetedly.

I use Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.10.

Where I can find a more verbose log on what happened to the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse switch to the Debug perspective (Menu Bar -> Window -> Open Perspective -> Debug). You will see a view called logcat with Android icon. Click on it, it will display the debugging/error messages.

Comment: The DDMS perspective is more appropriate IMHO.

Comment: This, but running logcat in a console is even better since Eclipse limits the buffer size and just stops working after a while.

Answer (score 2):

The error StackTrace can be explored via this console command:

```
adb logcat
```